# Try/ catch. как сделать чтобы ошибка обрабатывалась?

Tags: c#, octokit.net

Используется: Octokit.net
Имеется кнопка.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Authen_GitHub();

            string searchQuery_str = "winform";
            string lang_str = "";
            int num_page = 1;

            await SearchReposit(searchQuery_str, lang_str, num_page);

            VarAddValue();

            int step = 30;
            GridFill(step);
        }
```

В методе "VarAddValue()", из строки сразу выполняется переход к методу "GridFill(step)"

```
var repoLicen = await client.Repository.GetLicenseContents(instanceRepoId);
```

Вопрос.
Почему происходит переход к следующему методу?
Как исправить ошибку?

Видео - [ссылка](https://youtu.be/_6OmC-RZZxE)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Картинка1 - ссылка
Картинка2 - [ссылка](http://www.imageup.ru/img172/3189821/2018-10-13_10-39-16.png.html)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

//
using Octokit;

namespace rsh
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        GitHubClient client;        
        SearchRepositoriesRequest request_repo;        
        SearchRepositoryResult resultRepo;
        Repository instanceRepo;

        long instanceRepoId;

        string licensName; // лицензия Тип
        string licensUrl; // лицензия Урл        

        DataTable RepoTable;

        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public event Action<string> CatchExceptionE;

        // Аутентификация.        
        public void Authen_GitHub() // Аутентификация. GitHub 
        {   
            client = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("my-cool-app"));            
        } 



        public async Task<int> SearchReposit(string searchQuery_str, string lang_str, int num_page)
        {   // Поиск по "Реозитариям"            
            request_repo = new SearchRepositoriesRequest(searchQuery_str); 
            request_repo.Page = num_page;

            switch (lang_str)
            {
                case "C#":
                    request_repo.Language = Language.CSharp;
                    break;
            }

            // Коллекция репозитариев                         
            resultRepo = await client.Search.SearchRepo(request_repo);

            // Количество репозитариев            
            int countRepo_dec = Convert.ToInt32(resultRepo.TotalCount);

            // string 
            return countRepo_dec;
        }

        // Присваиваем значение переменным. Заполняем ДатаТабле
        public async void VarAddValue()
        {

            CreateDataTable(); // Создаём ДатаТабле             

            for (int i = 0; i <= 99; i++)
            {
                instanceRepo = resultRepo.Items[i];
                instanceRepoId = instanceRepo.Id;

                #region *** Лицензия. Извлекаем данные ***
                try
                {                    
                    var repoLicen = await client.Repository.GetLicenseContents(instanceRepoId);
                    // var licenVar = repoLicen.License.Name; // 

                        // *** переменные
                        licensName = repoLicen.License.Name; // лицензия Тип // MIT License"
                        licensUrl = repoLicen.HtmlUrl; // лицензия Урл // "https://github.com/danvanderboom/Xamarin-Forms-TreeView/blob/master/LICENSE"
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        string error = "*** License *** \r\n"                             
                                        + e.Message + "\r\n";
                        CatchExceptionE?.Invoke(error);                        
                 }
                    #endregion *** Лицензия ***

                    #region *** DataTable. Строки Добавить в dTablAddRowCls***
                    DataRow rowNew = RepoTable.NewRow();

                    rowNew["lic"] = licensName;
                    rowNew["lic_url"] = licensUrl;

                    RepoTable.Rows.Add(rowNew);
                #endregion

                GridFill(30);
            }
        }

        public DataTable CreateDataTable()
        {
            using (RepoTable = new DataTable())
            {   
                DataColumn column = new DataColumn();

                RepoTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("lic", typeof(string)));  //ПО. Лицензия
                RepoTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("lic_url", typeof(string)));  //ПО. Лицензия. Урл

                return RepoTable;
            }
        }

        // Заполнение "dataGridView1" данными
        public void GridFill(int step)
        {
            //  https://stackoverflow.com/a/12930975/9832524
            DataTable DtTblResult = RepoTable.AsEnumerable()
                            .Where((row, index) => index < step)
                            .CopyToDataTable();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = DtTblResult;
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Authen_GitHub();

            string searchQuery_str = "winform";
            string lang_str = "";
            int num_page = 1;

            await SearchReposit(searchQuery_str, lang_str, num_page);

            VarAddValue();

            int step = 30;
            GridFill(step);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что ваш метод `VarAddValue` — `async void`. Так делать не надо, сделайте из него `async Task` и добавьте `await` в точку вызова. Сочетание `async void` следует использовать только для обработчиков событий.

Comment: @VladD Работает. Не могли бы вы проверить всё ли правильно я сделал? Как по правилам форума нужно ? Вы наверное должны оформить ответ? `public async Task<DataTable> VarAddValue()
 {
   // ... Код ...
 }
 private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // ... Код ...
   await VarAddValue();

   int step = 30;
   GridFill(step);
}`

Comment: Да, напишу ответ, рад, что помогло!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Смотрите, в чем дело. Ваш метод `VarAddValue` объявлен как `async void`. Такие методы всегда работают по принципу fire and forget: как только в их коде встречается `await`, они выполняются асинхронно, и дождаться их невозможно, т. к. нету объекта `Task`!

Поэтому сочетание `async void` следует использовать только для обработчиков событий, в которых никто всё равно не дожидается окончания обработки.

В вашем случае просто сделайте из метода `VarAddValue` `async Task` и добавьте await в точку вызова.

Если вы хотите ещё и что-то вернуть из метода, можно сделать что-то наподобие `Task<DataTable>` и в точке вызова написать `var table = await VarAddValue()`, но это в вашем коде не обязательно.